# XSLT transformation, XPATH issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this xml here and I need to do an XSLT transformation

```
<store>
<users>
<user id="3">
</user>
<user id="4">
</user>
<user id="5">
</user>
</users>

<sellers>
<seller id="3"/>
<seller id="4"/> 
</sellers>
```

The thing is, I need an XPath that will access every seller's elements (only the sellers not the rest of the users) without searching by the specific id's of the sellers

Thank you

Comment: What about the expression "/store/sellers/seller" or "//seller?

Comment: I think what the OP means is to use the entries in `<sellers>` to identify `<user>` entries to be extracted, ignoring those users who don't appear in `<sellers>`

Answer (score 2):

Create a key for users:

```
<xsl:key name="user-by-id" match="user" select="@id"/>
```

Then to find the users who are referenced from seller elements, you can do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/store/sellers/seller">
   <xsl:variable name="user" select="key('user-by-id', @id)"/>
   <!-- now process $user -->
```